# Prompting Database Login when loading crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I've got a problem every time  i load my report on crystal. Always asking for database login  but when i enter my password(which is the password of my connection) it always says that  login failed.

This is my code:

```
    Dim _ReportLogonInfos As New TableLogOnInfos
    Dim _ReportLogonInfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim _ReportConInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    Dim _Tables As Tables
    Dim _Table As Table

    With _ReportConInfo
        .ServerName = "localhost"
        .DatabaseName = "database"
        .UserID = "root"
        .Password = "Qwerty123"
    End With
    Dim _Report As New rptPrntIss
    _Tables = _Report.Database.Tables
    For Each _Table In _Tables
        _ReportLogonInfo = _Table.LogOnInfo
        _ReportLogonInfo.ConnectionInfo = _ReportConInfo
        _Table.ApplyLogOnInfo(_ReportLogonInfo)

    Next
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _Report
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what you set, I also set the following (sorry this is in C# not VB.NET - hopefully you can translate):

1

```
        //SET DATASOURCE FOR EACH SUBREPORT IN REPORT
        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section section in CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.ReportDefinition.Sections)
        {
            // In each section we need to loop through all the reporting objects
            foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportObject reportObject in section.ReportObjects)
            {
                if (reportObject.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
                {
                    SubreportObject subReport = (SubreportObject)reportObject;
                    ReportDocument subDocument = subReport.OpenSubreport(subReport.SubreportName);

                    foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table table in subDocument.Database.Tables)
                    {
                        // Cache the logon info block
                        TableLogOnInfo logOnInfo = table.LogOnInfo;

                        // Set the connection
                        logOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;

                        // Apply the connection to the table!
                        table.ApplyLogOnInfo(logOnInfo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

2

```
        if (CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections.Count > 0)
            CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(server, db, crystalUser, pwd);
```

3

```
        CrystalReportSource2.ReportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon(crystalUser, pwd, server, db);
```

Comment: Thank You..  i'd already solved  it . thanks for this help..  u give me ideas.. so i can move on to my project. GODBLESS :)